# Unix printf does not format strings as expected - it prints the formatting string instead

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, grep

I want to write some ENV-Variables into a .txt file with the `printf` command (and ignore lines which are empty because the env variable is not set):

```
printf '%-79s' "${foo1}${bar1}" | grep -v '^\s\{79\}' >> foobar.txt
printf '%-79s' "${foo2}${bar2}" | grep -v '^\s\{79\}' >> foobar.txt
...
```

On my local WSL and Docker environment (centos 7) it works as expected. But on the servers where the script should run it prints only `79s` in the foobar.txt file:

```
cat foobar.txt
79s
79s
```

Does anybody have an idea why the `printf` command does not work as excpeted?

Feel free to suggest me other solutions. But I am also very interested why the command doesn't work as expected on my remote servers.

Comment: What's the content of the variables when you get that output?

Comment: The values of the variables are 12345 and LOE (foo1 and bar1). The others (foo2-foo10, bar2-bar10) are empty. I forgot to mention that the file foobar.txt contains 10 times the value 79s

Comment: We're missing a lot of context. How are you sending the code to the server "where it should run"? It sounds like the `%` character is being removed. You might try doubling it: `printf "%%-79s" ...`, but that is a pure guess on my part.